# On Chrome document.styleSheets is not updated when I add a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Apparently there is an issue with the property document.styleSheets in Google Chrome. The property is not updated after a new stylesheet is added.
To reproduce the issue simply run the following code:

```
    // Create the link element
    var element = document.createElement("link");
    element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    element.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    element.setAttribute("href", "external.css");

    // Add the link element
    console.log('Before add: ' + document.styleSheets.length);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    console.log('After add: ' + document.styleSheets.length);
```

When running in FireFox the console will show something like:

```
    Before add: 4
    After add: 5
```

When running in Chrome the console will show something like:

```
    Before add: 4
    After add: 4
```

Interestingly, the following code works correctly (return the same results) on both browsers:

```
    console.log('Before add: ' + document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].children);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
    console.log('After add: ' + document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].children);
```

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

I discovered this issue while writing and testing the following function to dynamically add CSS files to a web page:

```
function requiresCSS( name ) { 
    var sheets = document.styleSheets; 
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { 
        if (sheets[i].href && sheets[i].href.indexOf(name) !== -1) { 
            return; 
        } 
    }

    var link = document.createElement("link"); 
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css"; 
    link.href = name; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link); 
}
```

When trying to add CSS twice, the function works perfectly on Firefox but fails on Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding an **external** file and then checking for it immediately. It's not surprising that you wouldn't see it yet, the HTTP request is probably still outstanding. If you check back later, once the HTTP request is complete and the styles parsed and applied, you'll see it in `document.styleSheets`.

According to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element), you can use the `load` event on the link element to get a notification of when the resource has been loaded. So:

```
element.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log('After add: ' + document.styleSheets.length);
}, false);
console.log('Before add: ' + document.styleSheets.length);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

Of course, loading and parsing/applying may not be simultaneous, so if you still see a disparity, you may need a `setTimeout` in there:

```
element.addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('After add: ' + document.styleSheets.length);
    }, 0);
}, false);
console.log('Before add: ' + document.styleSheets.length);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

---

Re your function that tries to avoid adding a stylesheet twice, since the *element* is there reliably even if the entry in `document.styleSheets` isn't, I'd just look for the element:

```
function requiresCSS( name ) { 
    // If we already have an element for this stylesheet, return
    if (document.querySelector('link[rel=stylesheet][href="' + name + '"]') {
        return;
    }

    // Add it
    var link = document.createElement("link"); link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css"; link.href = name; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link); 
}
```

(You could also use `querySelector` for finding `head`, it'd be a bit more concise. `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` are supported on all modern browsers, and also IE8.)

Comment: From what I can tell, the [specification does state](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-DocumentStyle-styleSheets) that `document.styleSheets` should show the number of `<link>` elements as long as the `type` and `href` attributes are set correctly. But you could easily chalk this up as one of those edge-cases that inevitably pop up.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I added an explanation to my post on how I found the issue and why it is important, in my opinion.

Comment: @FrancoSF: If you want to detect whether you've added a `link` for a given stylesheet, I'd look for the `link`, not the stylesheet; I've added an example.

Comment: Note that a minimum time-out of 4ms is specified in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting) as the minimum value.

Comment: @BramVanroy: And note that browser implementations take very little notice of that, instead employing much more interesting algorithms. Specifying `0` does, regardless, mean "as soon as possible" (whether that's 4ms or ~0ms), which is all we're shooting for above.

Comment: Hm, I posted my comment because I thought some older versions of IE don't handle a zero-value well, but I can't seem to find any source for that. I rest my case.